# Input Unicode character string and output the corresponding character

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I have a Python program that stores a dictionary with Unicode number strings in it, then gets the string and prints out the actual character.
My code looks like this:

```
unicodeChars = {'bullet': 'u+2022'}
print(chr(unicodeChars['bullet']))
```

But when I run the program, it prints out the Unicode character string, (`u+2202`), not the actual character. How would I make my program do this?

I'm using Python 3 in a [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11) 64-bit laptop.

Comment: `chr(int(unicodeChars['bullet'][2:]))`

Comment: Take a look at the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was `chr(int(unicodeChars['bullet'][2:]))`.
Thank you, @sahasrara62 for the answer!

Comment: This is not right. Unicode characters are base 16, and you are converting them using base 10. Your code will print `ߦ`, but the right character for `u+20222` is `•`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). You will see that you really are looking for this instead:

```py
unicode_chars = {'bullet': '\u2022'}
print(unicode_chars['bullet'])
```